# Difficulty understanding Inverse functions are being used by Solve

Tags: differential-equations

I am still having difficulty with the differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=y^2-y,\quad y(0)=2$$

Consider:

```
In[31]:= Clear[y];
Clear[Derivative];
sol = DSolve[{y'[t] == y[t]^2 - y[t], y[0] == 2}, y[t], t]

During evaluation of In[31]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

Out[33]= {{y[t] -> -(2/(-2 + E^t))}}

In[34]:= y[t_] := y[t] /. First[sol]

In[35]:= y[0]

During evaluation of In[35]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

Out[35]= Hold[y[0]]
```

Also, the command Plot[y[t],{t,0,3}] will not produce a plot. What is going on?

Now, I can get the following to work.

```
In[42]:= Clear[y];
Clear[Derivative];
sol = DSolve[{y'[t] == y[t]^2 - y[t], y[0] == 2}, y[t], t]

During evaluation of In[42]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

Out[44]= {{y[t] -> -(2/(-2 + E^t))}}

In[48]:= y[t_] = y[t] /. First[sol]

Out[48]= -(2/(-2 + E^t))

In[49]:= y[0]

Out[49]= 2
```

However, if I am going to use Mathematica to help teach differential equations, I have to be able to explain what is going on with the first example to my students. Right now, I can't do that. I do need help. I do understand that the solution "blows up to infinity" as $t$ approaches $\ln 2$ from the left, but what has that to do with simplify evaluating the function at $t=0$ in the first example?

Answer (score 4):

I looked at [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Solve/ifun.html) and it said "the inverse function that is used to represent the solution gives only one of the solutions to [the] equation." I believe what that means is in order to solve the equation Mathematica solved for another variable in terms of $y$ and then took the inverse to find $y$, but that inverse wasn't one-to-one, so some information *may* have been lost.

They give an example if their documentation of a trig equation with infinitely many solutions. I do not believe that is the case here given the uniqueness of the solutions to linear ODEs.

Edit: I missed half your question. In Mathematica := means "set delayed", and it sets a symbol equal to some arbitrary code without evaluating it. So the big problem is you're defining y[t] in terms of an equation of y[t] which causes an infinite recursion. As = is "set" it evaluates the code first, thus avoiding such recursion.

Answer (score 4):

[David Etler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/22748/david-etler) is right, it's a matter of evaluation order rather than inverse functions.

The problem can be reproduced with the following simple example:

```
Clear[y, t, sol, Derivative]
y[t_] := y[t] /. First[sol]
y[0]
```

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

Wait, you clear `sol`, too! Though you reproduced the warning, this may be a different issue, isn't it?! Well, no, it's just the same case. We know in this case the function definition is stored in the `DownValues`, let's check the `DownValues` of `y`:

```
y // DownValues
Clear[y]
sol = {{y[t] -> t}};
y[t_] := y[t] /. First[sol]
y // DownValues
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[y[t_]] :> (y[t] /. First[sol])}
> {HoldPattern[y[t_]] :> (y[t] /. First[sol])}
> ```

As you see, whether `sol` owns a definition doesn't influence the `DownValues` of y, it's a product of the `HoldAll` attribute of `SetDelayed`(`:=`).

But the definition of `sol` still exists, and it may come into play in the subsequent evaluation, doesn't it? Sadly, once again the answer is no, all because `ReplaceAll`(`/.`) doesn't hold i.e. it **doesn't** own a attribute like `HoldAll`, `HoldFirst`, etc.

What will happen to the argument of a function that doesn't own a hold-class attribute? It will first evaluate those arguments, from left to right:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, y_] = x + y
f[1 + 2, 3 + 4] // Trace
```

> ```
> {{1 + 2, 3}, {3 + 4, 7}, f[3, 7], 3 + 7, 10}
> ```

This is exactly what happened inside `ReplaceAll`. When evaluating `y[0]`, the rule stored as the `DownValues` of `y` matches and the expression evaluates to `y[0] /. First[sol]`. `ReplaceAll`(`/.`) doesn't hold anything so the argument of `ReplaceAll[y[0], First[sol]]` evaluate from left to right: `y[0]` is evaluated again, and it never ends, with `sol` always stand aside.

As you've noticed, the problem can be solved by changing `SetDelayed`(`:=`) into `Set`(`=`) in the function definition:

```
Clear[y]
y[t_] = y[t] /. First[sol];
y[0]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

This is because `Set`  owns the attribute `HoldRest` i.e. things in the right side of `=` will be evaluate once the function is defined and those annoying structure no longer exists now:

```
y // DownValues
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[y[t_]] :> t}
> ```

Another way to fix the problem is to use `Evaluate`:

```
y[t_] := Evaluate[y[t] /. First[sol]];
y[0]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Well, just an aside, I know some beginners have a tendency to use `:=` everywhere. This may be because they're once… Er… hurted by `=` in situations like

```
Clear[x, y, z];
z[x_] = D[y, x];
z[x^2]
(* Why the answer isn't 2 x ! *)

Clear[y]
x = 1;
y[x_] = 2 x;
y[2]
(* Why the answer is not 4 ! *)
```

or simply because the syntax highlighting of `:=` looks better. (The arguments in the right hand side are now all green, neat!) But as shown in this post, this isn't really a good habit, using `Set` or `SetDelayed` really depends, and isn't hard to decide, once you've had the evaluation order issue in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

The equation can, of course, be solved analytically.  Doing so gives the solution,

```
Log[(y - 1) / y] = t + c[1]
```

with `c[1]` to be determined from the boundary condition.  To obtain an explicit expression for *y*, one must use the inverse of `Log`, namely `Exp`.  This is what is meant by using inverse functions.  Sometimes, using inverse functions omits terms.  For instance, inverting `Sin[θ]` to obtain `θ` can omit additive multiples of `2 Pi`.